# What is meant by Capacity to Perform Juristic Acts

Tags: property, jurisdiction, common-law, minor, court

What is the difference between Capacity to Act and Legal Capacity?

Comment: What country? Where did you read this? Can you provide context?

Comment: Legal terms do not have universal meanings in the abstract. Their meaning can only be interpreted in context. Many legal terms have different meanings in different contexts an different meanings in different jurisdictions. Without knowing why you would care about the difference it really isn't possible to provide a meaningful and accurate answer.